# How to open a Monero CLI wallet by specifying the wallet name?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet

I have wallet file. How I can open it from command line parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Use the parameter: `--wallet-file <file name here>`. E.g.

```
monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file MyWallet
```

(assuming you have a wallet file named "MyWallet" in the current working directory)